# remove line with substring from a file in unix

Tags: sed

I have a file(abc.txt) which contains list of files. Sample content as below. I want to remove those lines which contains .tar names and keep all others which contain .tar.gz

```
HUW_3356_DLM4_00_00.tar.gz
HUW_3359_DLM4_01_00.tar.gz
HUW_3459_DLM4_02_00.tar
HUW_4359_DLM4_03_00.tar
HUW_3360_DLM4_02_00.tar.gz
```

I tried, but it doesn't work

```
sed -i "/*.tar/d" abc.txt
```

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"? What result do you get?

Comment: @FelixKling it doesn't remove line with .tar

Comment: expected out is:HUW_3356_DLM4_00_00.tar.gz
HUW_3359_DLM4_01_00.tar.gz
HUW_3360_DLM4_02_00.tar.gz

Comment: Edit your question and insert expected output in the file. You want to remove all lines?

Comment: `sed` expects to be passed a regular expression, but `*.tar` is not a valid regular expression. Looks more like a glob. You want `\.tar$`.

Answer (score 1):

Match end of line with `$`. Note that the expression is a regex not a globulation, dot needs to be escaped to match a dot.

```
sed -i '/\.tar$/d' abc.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
sed -n '/\.tar\.gz$/p' Input_file
```

Use `-i` option in `sed` to save output into Input_file itself.

From man page `man sed`:

> -n, --quiet, --silent
>
> suppress automatic printing of pattern space

For `p` option:

> p      Print the current pattern space.